# How to search for multiple filename extensions in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-search, file-search

How can I search for multiple filename extensions in Windows 8?

**Semicolon does not work**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OR statement to search for multiple file types at once. Like so: *.xml OR *.bat
I just tested it myself *<sup>(Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit)</sup>* and it works like a charm

<sup><sup>https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/acb151bd-48e9-4d87-84ed-a01d150ea300/search-multiple-files-types-in-w7?forum=w7itprogeneral</sup></sup>

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 you can use **OR** to search for multiple items, try that.